# Optimal strategy in rolling a dice with N faces

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm learning how dynamic programming world works. For this reason i'm trying to resolve the following problem : 
 Simon take part to the final round of a game show in which he can roll one dice a number of times that depends on the jackpot collected from the previous game show's phases. The dice has n faces, which each of them represent a prize (assume equal to the number issued). Simon for roll the dice must pay a little fee (suppose for sake of simplicity that this fee is $1 for each turn). Furthermore, suppose that x represents Simon's jackpot so that he can play at most x turns. At each turn he can decide to quit the game winning the best prize found so far, reduced by the sum of all fees. The goal is to find the optimal strategy in order to maximize Simon's final reward, designing an algorithm with time complexity equal to O(n^2 * x).

**First attempt**
 My first attempt it was thinking how the probability is involved in this problem. Naturally, a prize has a probability of going out equals to all other. So, i considered that when Simon complete a turn, his decision for continue to the next turn is based on the probability to find a better prize than the current one. Maybe i'm wrong, but i considered that if the probability to find a better prize is greater than the probability to find a worst prize, then Simon proceed with next turn, otherwise he stops at the current turn and the best discounted prize so far will be returned. However in this case, i got an algorithm with time complexity equal to O(x).

Naturally, i don't request the solution to the problem. I would like to know what i'm actually missing in my reasoning. Can someone tell me what is wrong ?
Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: Simon wants to maximize the expected payout. Consider n=500 and x=100, and the first roll is 300. Simon's payout after one roll is $299. If the second roll is 10, Simon's payout after two rolls is $298. But if the second roll is 370, Simon's payout after two rolls is $368. So on each roll, Simon is only risking $1, but the payout can increase by a substantial amount. That continues until Simon has a very good roll, or simply doesn't have any more money to risk.

Answer (score 1):

I think our algorythm is correct, but O(n^2 * x) means the overall complexity for calculating all of the possible cases.
There are X steps, in each each step there are n different cases (The best prize we got already) and in order to calculate if it would worth to continue we need to test the n possible outcome of the next roll.

Comment: Can you explain to me why in each turn i need to check all the possibilities and not only check if i can get a better prize or not in constant time ? For example, if n = 500 and in the first turn i got $200, then the probability to proceed to the next turn is 1- 199/500, which will be greater than the probability to find a worst prize. I will repeat this procedure for each turn, but as i said previously it will take constant time.